# Referencing datarange of pivot table with multiple row fields

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

Ok I got referencing the data ranges of a pivot table with a single pivot field in either the columns or rows:

```
BevPvt.PivotFields("Sum of Amount ").DataRange.Select
For Each deposit1 In BevPvt.PivotFields("Sum of Amount ").DataRange
```

etc.

but what if I have multiple data fields within columns or rows, IE moving two data fields to the row box (for instance POS location and Date). I want to find matching dates and matching locations. Is the only solution to move a row field (for example location) to a column?

Answer (score 0):

One way of working around this issue is by using offset(0,-1)

I turn off subtotals for the first datafield in the rowfield box, then have my macro searching the value field data range - if it finds vbNullString then the offset(0,-1) records the name of the data field in the first rowfield position, then if it is not a vbNullString then the offset gives the name of the data field in the second rowfield position.

Looks like this (the removal of subtotals is not in this portion of code)

```
For Each deposit2 In CHMBAll.PivotFields("Sum of Original Deposit Total").DataRange
If deposit2 = vbNullString Then
lockbox = deposit2.Offset(0, -1).Value
End If
If deposit2 <> vbNullString Then
If deposit2.Interior.Color = 5296274 Then
DepDate = deposit2.Offset(0, -1).Value
For CHMBi = 2 To CHMBLR
If Cells(CHMBi, 5).Value = lockbox Then
If Cells(CHMBi, 3).Value = DepDate Then
Cells(CHMBi, 6).Interior.Color = 5296274
End If
End If
Next CHMBi
End If
End If
Next deposit2
```